# Hide Navigation bar for `TabView` not working

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, ios14, tabview

In swiftUI, iOS14. I can not hide the navigation bar of `TabView`. Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView() {
                List {
                    Text("Hi!")
                    Text("How are you?")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true) // not working!!
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? How to resolve this problem?[image: Navigation Bar exists!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move `.navigationBarHidden(true)` **inside to TabView**.

```swift
  struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                TabView() {
                    List {
                        Text("Hi!")
                        Text("How are you?")
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true) //<= here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this hides the navigationbar, check I have added  .navigationBarHidden(true)  to the List

Comment: Oh! Need to add code inside `TabView`. Magic!

Comment: Not works for me. IOS 15

Comment: add your full code .. @BinhHo